# How to unit test form validation on angular using ngx-formly

Tags: angular, angular-forms, angular-formly, ngx-formly

I'm using ngx-formly (on V5) to generate a form with an input and a checkbox (here is the FormlyFieldConfig):

```
field: FormlyFieldConfig = {
className: 'database-header',
validators: {
  validation: [
    { name: 'maxLengthIfExternal', options: { errorPath: 'name' } },
  ],
},
fieldGroup: [
  {
    className: 'align-left',
    key: 'name',
    type: 'input',
    defaultValue: '',

    templateOptions: {
      required: true,
      label: 'Database Name',
      pattern: HYPHEN_REGEX_PATTERN_VALIDATION,
      maxLength: 32,
    },
    validation: {
      messages: {
        pattern:
          'Allowed characters: a-z 0-9 -, must start with lower case letter and end with an alphanumeric character',
      },
    },
  },
  {
    key: 'external',
    type: 'checkbox',
    templateOptions: {
      label:
        'External',
    },
  },
],
```

};

I have a custom validator that is checking if the checkbox is checked (maxLengthIfExternal). If it is, the name input cannot be more than 8 characters.

I want to unit test (jest) the validation for this form: setting the input to more then 8 characters then clicking the checkbox and checking that the form is now invalid.

I can't find any documentation on how to unit test validation on formly. Does anyone know how to achieve that?

Answer (score 1):

You can do so with testing library, as long as you have some visual cue when the form is invalid. For example, let's say we have a submit button that will only be enabled if the form is valid. You could write the test like this:

```js
it('should be invalid if the input value has more than 8 chars and the checkbox is ticked', () => {
  const input = screen.getByRole('input')
  const checkbox = screen.getByRole('checkbox')

  userEvent.type(input, '123456789')
  userEvent.click(checkbox)

  expect(screen.getByRole('button', { name: /submit/i  })).shouldBeDisabled()
})
```

You can write a similar test using Angular testing selectors, it's just a different interface.

Comment: This is not going to work because of formly. Unless there is a way to build the form within the unit test itsefl, and this is what I'm serching for.

Comment: I don't get it. Why wouldn't it work with formly?